# Add rolling pyshics to sphere model at gazebo

Tags: ros

i make a ball model at gazebo by making sdf file but it's not moving
how can i make a ball rolling?

my sdf code right below

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<sdf version='1.4'>
    <model name="sphere">
     <link name='base_link'>
            <pose>0 0 .1 0 0 0</pose>

        <collision name='collision'>
              <geometry>
                <sphere>
                  <radius>0.03</radius>
                </sphere>
              </geometry>
        </collision>
        <visual name='visual'>
            <geometry>
                <sphere>
                <radius>0.03</radius>
                </sphere>
            </geometry>
            <material>
                <diffuse>1 0 0 1</diffuse>
                            <ambient>1 0 0 1</ambient>
                </material>
            </visual>
        </link>
    </model>
</sdf>
```

help me!!!

Comment: Spawn it on an inclined surface? Add a torque?

Comment: Force is related to acceleration/velocity. If you want something to move, you need to apply a force. Forces are not default properties of the objects; objects can be acted upon by a force. SDL's determine compile time attributes; forces are run time. At run time, you need to apply a force; what ros code are you using to do so? As 2b-t said, gravity? What do you actually want, what's actual end goal?